# Has openfire implemented xmpp XEP-0234 Jingle File Transfer?

Tags: iphone, ios, xmpp

I searched source code of openfire , but did not find any file working for XEP-0234. Can anyone else give me an answer, as I am new to openfire and not sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special server code required for XEP-0234. The server must route only iq stanzas for it from client to client. This is defined in the XMPP core protocols and supported by every XMPP compliant server.